# 301 redirect subdomain to another domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to 301 redirect a subdomain to another domain with htaccess.

I want:

```
A: www.subdomain.domain1.se
B: subdomain.domain1.se
C: subdomain.domain1.se/anything/anything.anything#anything?anything
```

to redirect to:

```
A: www.domain2.se
B: www.domain2.se
C: www..domain2.se/anything/anything.anything#anything?anything
```

Also I need to know where to put the file (in subdomain directory or root directory). Best would be if I could put the htaccess file in the subdomain ddirectory if possible.

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^c\.domain1\.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.se/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you messing RewriteBase / in the code

regular redirect 301 work like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.domain1\.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.se%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

However note that URL part after hash is not sent to web server hence cannot be handled by Apache mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thanks. But I still want www.domain1.se and any other subdomain for domain1.se to work. And the htaccess file I have access to is located in  "/public_html/c.domain1.se/". Any ideas?

Comment: A and B works but for C I get "subdomain.domain1.se/kontakt -> You don't have permission to access /kontakt on this server." Any ideas? Thanks Anubhava!

Comment: As per these rules `subdomain.domain1.se/kontakt` should become `www.domain2.se/kontakt` in your browser. Isn't this happening?

Comment: No, I recive error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /kontakt on this server." Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any other code in this .htaccess or any other .htaccess in your system?

Comment: But shouldn't it be something (HERE) "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.domain1\.se(HERE)$ [NC]" to match anything?

Comment: In regex `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*?subdomain\.domain1\.se$ [NC]` same as `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.domain1\.se$ [NC]` since all we care about is HOST name that ends with `subdomain\.domain1\.se`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38608/discussion-between-user1087110-and-anubhava)